# I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to color a cell in ColumnF only if 1) it contains specific text & 2) if ColumnG<ColumnH

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I've tried "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" & the following formula: `=AND((iftext(w)),G1<H1)`

ie color a cell in Column F if that Column F cell contains "W" AND G1<H1.

But idk how to add a 2nd concurrent condition for the Column F cell to contain "W"

[image]

When my formula was simpler ("=G1<H1"), the conditional formatting worked perfectly.

Comment: `=AND(F1="W",G1<H1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[image]

---

```
=(F2="W")*(G2<H2)
```

---

`*` acts as `AND()` function here.